# Solr cores are not switched when putting SXA 1.7 in live-mode

Tags: sxa, sxa-storefront, habitathome

I switched my SXA Storefront & Habitat Home based site to live mode by setting the database to `master` in `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Site Grouping/Site`.

I was expecting the site to use the `master` Solr cores as well, but noticed that the `web` Solr cores are still used.

Did I miss a setting?
Why aren't the Solr cores switched?

Comment: Did you publish /sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Site Grouping/Site item?

Comment: Yes, published & confirmed that the `master` database is actually used.

Comment: Which version of SXA are you using? I'm asking because we had a bug in `IndexResolver` which was causing such behaviour. This is already fixed but I would need to check in which version.

Comment: Using SXA 1.7.1 rev. 180604 for 9.0

Comment: I can confirm that it has been fixed in SXA 1.8.1. Are you planning to upgrade?

Comment: Will wait for [HabitatHome.Commerce](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Commerce) to upgrade.

Comment: Is this a blocker for you? I can provide you with some code so that you will be able to fix InexResolver on your side and replace the implementation in the DI container.

Comment: No blocker can work around it, but thanks!

Comment: Closing; as question resolution has nothing to do with question being asked in OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Solr cores are not properly switched using SXA 1.7. Upgrading SXA to 1.8.1 solves the issue.

Workaround, when upgrading to SXA 1.8.1 is not an option, could be to fix the `IndexResolver` which causes the problem.